# SQLite: duplicate row in table with a unique column

Tags: sqlite

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE aTable (aCol TEXT UNIQUE, ...);
INSERT INTO aTable VALUES ( 'one', ... );
```

I need to duplicate rowid 1 and then change it

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO aTable SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE rowid = 1;
UPDATE aTable SET aCol = 'new unique value' WHERE rowid = 1;
COMMIT;
```

But that violates the UNIQUE constraint.

How can I retrieve the pre-transaction state of rowid 1?

Of course I could do a SELECT before the transaction, and bind its results to a prepared INSERT statement. I'm also aware of the following, but are there are other methods?

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE aTemp AS SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE rowid = 1;
...
DROP TABLE aTemp;
```

***Updated***
More context: `aTable` is a history table with normal order, later rows are later versions. However one row (rowid 1) is *in progress* and therefore not in the history. Thus rowid 1 must be updated to have the latest unique value.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious, but couldn't you simply do something like:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT col1, 'New value', col3 FROM other_table WHERE col1 = 1
```

...which would duplicate the row apart from col2. What you've not mentioned is where the new unique value will come from, so a bit of guidance around that be helpful.

Comment: I need the new unique value to land in rowid 1, and the existing value to land in the new row.

Comment: If the new row is a duplicate of the original row, does it matter which row gets the new value?

Comment: Yes. In this app, rowid 1 has a special role, where it always has the latest unique value.

Comment: "In this app, rowid 1 has a special role . . ." No good can come from that.

Comment: It almost sounds like you're creating a history table, but in reverse (i.e., later row IDs have older history). Is this the case? If so, then you're better off turning it on it's head so rowid effectively becomes a version number.

Comment: @Catcall, the alternatives would create needless complexity in this context.

Comment: @ChrisJ, it is a history table but with normal order, later rows are later versions. However one row (rowid 1) is _in progress_ and therefore not in the history. It's convenient to leave this at rowid 1, which is where it gets created.

Comment: Short of rejigging the app so that in-progress rows are stored in a different table, or the table has an extra field (a bit field called isLatest or something) or using `max`, then there isn't a better way: re-engineering would give you simpler SQL (as in my answer) and a more robust solution, but beyond that there isn't much more that can be done. I have, however, added the context you've provided in these comments to the question - if there's any more pertinent details, then I'd advise adding them into the question as well: more context is a good thing so you get the right answer.

Comment: You're referring to max(rowid)? It'd only be simpler SQL for this one transaction. There's a LOT of other code manipulating this table.

Answer (score 1):

vlookup can be implemented

organize your data so that the value you look up is to the left of the return value you want to find.

Syntax

VLOOKUP (lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])